# Loop até ser verdadeiro - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, loop

Olá, tudo bem?

Estou precisando de uma ajuda com um código que estou montando, sou novo em Python e acredito que seja algo simples. O objetivo do código é validar se um arquivo com determinado nome já está disponível em um determinado caminho, sendo que este arquivo é salvo diariamente em horários diferentes.

Basicamente, o código verifica se o arquivo já existe na pasta e se não existir (não foi salvo ainda), ele deve aguardar alguns minutos e realizar a consulta novamente. Porém, aparentemente, o código não realiza a consulta após o sleep.

```
import os
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import time

dia=datetime.today()- timedelta(days=1)
dia2= dia.strftime('%d%m%y')
 
arquivo="PROD_"+dia2

caminho=r"C:\Users\Downloads\pasta2"


for file in os.listdir(caminho):
    if file.startswith(arquivo) ==True:
        print(arquivo)
    else:
        #time.sleep(120)
        print("arquivo ainda não disponivel")
```

Já tentei incluir o while também, mas aparentemente não funcionou.

Obrigado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você está percorrendo a lista de arquivos existentes no diretório, e uma única vez. Eu tentaria a seguinte lógica: "enquanto não existir o arquivo tal, não saia daqui". Isso significa um loop `while`, e dentro dele uma verificação direta se tal [arquivo existe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.isfile). Algo assim:

```
while not os.path.isfile(caminho_completo):
    print("arquivo ainda não disponivel")
    time.sleep(120)

# Aqui você segue considerando que o arquivo já está disponível
```

Comment: Ressaltando que `caminho_completo` é a junção das variáveis `caminho` e `arquivo`, algo como `caminho_completo = os.path.join(caminho, arquivo)`.

Comment: Isso, obrigado pelo complemento

Comment: certo, mas só mais uma duvida. eu não tenho o nome do arquivo completo, ele salvo diariamente com o nome "PROD_datadodia" + alguns numeros e letras aleatorios. esse caminho_completo vai funcionar se eu unir o "caminho" e o "arquivo"?

Comment: @JoãoMartins Não, você precisa saber o nome exato do arquivo para verificar se ele existe.

Comment: Então dentro do while você precisa do for que você já tinha, varrendo o diretório e verificando se cada nome de arquivo começa com o prefixo que você espera. Mude o while para `while True` e quebre o laço se encontrar o arquivo dentro do for.

Comment: aparentemente deu certo com o nome parcial, mas tambem montei do jeito que falou. Ficaria algo assim?
while True:
    for file in os.listdir(caminho):
        if file.startswith(arquivo) ==False:
        print("arquivo ainda não disponivel")
        time.sleep(120)
#continuação

Comment: Inclua um `break 2` para sair dos dois loops quando encontrar o arquivo. @JoãoMartins

Answer (score 0):

Em qualquer linguagem a instrução *for* significa "enquanto". Tendo isso em vista o seu *for* quer dizer:

```
enquanto conter file em caminho 
execute
```

Como o arquivo não está dentro da pasta, ou seja, não contem *file* em caminho, o seu for não sera executado e apos o primeiro loop será encerrado. Acredito que o que voce deseja seja:
`

```
for file not in os.listdir(caminho):
    if file.startswith(arquivo) == True:
        print(arquivo)
    else:
        #time.sleep(120)
        print("arquivo ainda não disponivel")`
```

Ou seja enquanto file não existir em caminho continua o loop.

Comment: Obrigado pelo retorno Rafael, tentei aqui mas não funcionou. Primeiro que ele acusou erro de syntax invalida (mesmo nao estando) e segundo que eu não tenho o loop pronto, acredito que so funcionará se eu tiver o loop

Comment: Na verdade, `while` é que significa enquanto. O `for` significa "para", ou para cada", ou algo similar.

Comment: Nem toda a linguagem de programação possui constructos para loops. Em geral linguagens cujo o paradigma seja Funcional, Lógico ou Baseado em Regras o identificador `for` não possui atribuição alguma.